# How do I printf a pointer to character array inside a function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf, scanf

I'm trying to make my own simple test in c. Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void assert(char *first, char *second);

int main(void) {
    char first[1000];
    char second[1000];

    printf("Enter first string: ");
    scanf("%s", first);
    printf("Enter second string: ");
    scanf("%s", second);

    assert(*first, *second);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void assert(char *first, char *second){
    if( first == second ){
        printf("Test Passed: these strings are the same");
    }else{
        printf("Test Failed: expected %s but returned %s", first, second);
    }
}
```

The problem is the printf inside the else statement in assert. When my code gets to that line it brakes. How can I fix this?

Comment: you're comparing addresses, not strings themselves

Comment: use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()`.

Comment: function call change to `assert(first, second);`. and `if( first == second ){` change to `if( strcmp(first, second)==0 ){`

Comment: Do you want the same or equal strings? Also, defining `assert` is a *bad* idea, look at `assert.h`. Next, you might have a buffer-overflow on reading your strings, limit it to 999+sentinel: `%999s`

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you warnings about this code? Or are you ignoring them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugs:

1. `assert` may be defined by the implementation, defining it yourself with external linkage is [**Undefined Behavior (UB)**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984).

   > #### 7.2 Diagnostics `<assert.h>`
   >
   > [...]
   >   2 The assert macro shall be implemented as a macro, not as an actual function. If the
   >   macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function, the behavior is undefined
2. You read a string of unlimited length into a fixed-length buffer: buffer-overflow: **UB**
   Use `%999s` for 999 characters plus sentinel
3. You do not check for error on calling `scanf`, potentially resulting in use of an uninitialized buffer: Potentially no terminator found: **UB**
4. You compare two pointers for equality (and the strings thus for same-ness), not the strings for equality. Include `<string.h>` and use

   ```
   if(!strcmp(first, second))
   ```

Other observations:

1. `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` is superfluous, `main` has implicit `return 0;` at the end since C99.

   - That makes `#include <stdlib.h>` superfluous.
2. Defining functions before first use lets you drop the forward-declaration.

Answer (score 1):

- When you are sending the array to your `assert` function, you should send the base address of it.Like this: `assert(first,second);`
- For comparing string in C you need to use strcmp function. It retuns `0` if both are equal.
  Include `string.h` in your code to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void string_assert( const char *first, const char *second )
{
    if ( strcmp( first, second ) == 0 ) 
    {
        printf( "Test Passed: these strings are the same" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Test Failed: expected %s but returned %s", first, second );
    }
}   


int main( void )
{

    char first[1000];
    char second[1000];

    printf( "Enter first string: " );
    scanf( "%s", first );

    printf( "Enter second string: " );
    scanf( "%s", second );

    string_assert( first, second );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error, potentially multiple definitions: `assert`

Comment: @Deduplicator You are wrong. Neither error will occur.

Comment: `7.2 Diagnostics <assert.h> [...] 2 The assert macro shall be implemented as a macro, not as an actual function. If the
macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual function, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh, you are write. Then the function shall be renamed.